# Could QueryInterface() provide us with nullptr when succeed?

Tags: c++, com, hresult, nullptr, queryinterface

Imagine a situation:

```
CComPtr<IGraphBuilder> pGraph;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraph));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    CComPtr<IMediaControl> pControl;
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pControl));
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {...}
}
```

I wonder, if `pControl` could ever be nullptr inside last block `{...}`. The question occurred, because I saw that code:

```
if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && pControl)
{...}
```

I consider that part `&& pControl` as a redundant one. Am I right?

Comment: According to the com spec it is redundant.... but nothing's stopping a bad coder from implementing QueryInterface themself and having it give a null pointer, so perhaps this version provides a little bit of protection against that

Comment: This kind of code is generally a pretty bad idea.  But it depends on what kind of support you are willing to provide.  If you can readily ignore a "it doesn't work" support request, all you are ever going to get with no way to repro it, then it is okay I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

`QueryInterface()` is *required* to provide a valid (so non-null) interface pointer on success *and* a null pointer on failure. However you don't know whether some specific implementation follows that rule and the code you cite most likely tries to be defensive.

That said, the following

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraph));
```

also calls `QueryInterface()` under the hood to retrieve the pointer to the requested interface. If the code wants to be defensive it should check that `pGraph` is non-null on success too.

The problem here is you don't know how bad it is when you get `S_OK` and a null pointer. Suppose `QueryInterface()` works like this (***really bad code follows, not for use anywhere***):

```
HRESULT TheClass::QueryInterface( REFIID iid, void** ppv )
{
    if( iid == SomeSpecificIID ) {
        AddRef();
        *ppv = 0; //BAD IDEA, BAD CODE, JUST DON'T
        return S_OK;
    } else {
       //whatever
    }
}
```

great, the defensive code will avoid dereferencing a null pointer retrieved here together with `S_OK` returned but reference count will be incorrect - noone will have a chance to call matching `Release()`. So you instantiate such an object, then call `QueryInterface()` which works as above, the refcount is now 2, then you `Release()` the object once and it leaks. How bad it happens to turn out depends on a lot of factors.

Same with `CoCreateInstance()` - it calls the same `QueryInterface()` under the hood. Both may be broken and your mileage may vary both with and without checking the retrieved pointer against null.